# How do I prove that something is a suffcient but not necessary condition?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

How do I prove that something is a suffcient but not necessary condition? I do not think I understand necessary and sufficient conditions very well. A question I have attempted is phrased as follows:

By considering $(x^2+gx+h)(x-k)$, or otherwise, show that $g^2 > 4h$ is a **sufficient** condition but not a **necessary** condition for the inequality $(g-k)^2 > 3(h-gk)$.

So far my argument is this:

If $g^2 > 4h$ then we know that there are two distinct turning points, and therefore $f'(x) = 0$ has two distinct solutions and, therefore the discriminant of $f'(x) > 0 $, after some algebraic manipulation leads me to the following statement:

$(g-k)^2 > 3(h-gk)$.

I am aware that I have not fully answered the question, and I am unsure of how to prove that it is sufficient, but not necessary. I wonder if someone could help with incorporating this into my argument.

Comment: Find $g,h,k$ that satisfy the inequality but do not satisfy $g^2 >4h$.

Comment: Could you explain how I’ve proved sufficiency?

Comment: To prove something is a mammal it is sufficient to prove it is an elephant (if for some reason that is easier).  All elephants are mammals; it's impossible to be an elephant and not be a mammal.  So if you've managed to prove something was an elephant you have *sufficiently* shown it was a mammal and you don't need to do anything else.  But it's not *nescessary* to prove it is an elephant to prove it is a mammal.  It could be a mamal *without being an elephant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking.

Consider the quadratic $(g-k)^2 -3(h-gk) = k^2+gk -3h +g^2$. Then this will be positive for all $k$ **iff** it is true for the minimising value of $k$.

The minimising value of $k$ is $k=- {g \over 2}$, and the above expression reduces to
${3 \over 4} (g^2-4h)$.

Hence we see that  $g^2 > 4h$ **iff** $(g-k)^2 -3(h-gk) > 0$ for all $k$.
This is an equivalence.

However, if we choose $g=0$, $h=1$ $k=2$ then $(g-k)^2 -3(h-gk) > 0$ but
$g^2 \le 4h$.

Hence if $g^2 > 4h$ then $(g-k)^2 -3(h-gk) > 0$ for all $k$, but there are $g,h,k$ such that $(g-k)^2 -3(h-gk) > 0$ for all $k$, but $g^2 \not> 4h$.